# How to write number sequence and join with table in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

[How to write dax formula like lag function without circular dependency in Excel Power Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78065129/how-to-write-dax-formula-like-lag-function-without-circular-dependency-in-excel)

I have been facing the problem above ,but the circular dependency seems to be inevitable.

So I will ask another way to solve.

In power query ,the function List.Generate is available for number sequence.

So I want to make new column as generate number sequence ,
and join it to the table.

What should I do for it?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample data ***as text which can be copy/pasted*** as well as a screen shot of your expected outcome ***from that data***, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)  Suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, in your question, please explain the algorithm you want to use to develop the values in your joined column and show the M-Code you have tried and where you have run into problems.